# How to Include default warning icon into pictureBox

Tags: c#, icons, picturebox

I want to set a picture box to the default visual studios warning icon.

So, I want to use this:

```
MessageBoxIcon.Warning
```

And format it to use instead of the system icon below:

```
this.pictureBoxWarning.Image = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();
```

The reason I want to do this is consistency reasons. I am making a custom dialog box and want it to look similar to the default one we use in our program with the dialog box.

Comment: Did you have a question?  A problem? You probably ought to store it to a variable so you can properly dispose of it and/or create only one of them

Answer (score 1):

If you open "%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll" with Visual Studio you will be presented with some folders, one should be named "Icon". In this folder, search the file called "161", right-click and then click export. That should be the exact same icon as used by the message box.

In case that is not what you wanted, this site contains the icons stored in various system files: http://www.unawave.de/windows-7/win7-icons.html

Answer (score 0):

simply save the image of the icon, resize if needed, then set the image